# Invisible font display issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I seem to be getting a problem where my fonts aren't displaying properly until the dom is manipulated somehow after the initial load. The page is https://www.gemalley.com/ - fonts appear blank or invisible in Safari/Chrome until for instance the menu icon is clicked, or the first banner animation is triggered. They also don't work on firefox or ie at all for me.

Haven't a clue why this is happening so would much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some code or a JSfiddle so we can try to figure out what may be happening?

Comment: It's hard to recreate the issue in JSfiddle really - the stylesheet for my font-face import is here - https://media.gemalley.com/styles/fonts.css 

I have used fonts.com for other sites and never had this issue which is why I'm having trouble figuring out what it is.